# how to make vpython .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, vpython

I have a simple script using vpython (just  testing) and I want to create a .exe file with pyinstaller.

This is the script:

```
from visual import*
box()
```

Then I run in the console:

```
pyinstaller sss.py
```

But the .exe dont work(obviously)

I've been googling about how to make the .spec file for vpython but dont find nothing.

Also tried making this .spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['sss.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\hdfh\\Documents\\Python Scripts'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=(['visual','vis','visual_common','viddle']),
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='sss.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='sss')
```

But it dindt work

Answer (score 1):

I will reponse myself, maybe it helps someone.

When pyinstaller is used with vpython and you try to run the .exe file, it has problem for find the TGA archives placed in

```
C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\visual_common
```

So we have to edit the archive materials.py

```
C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\visual_common\materials.py
```

Here we look for the code

```
import sys
if hasattr(sys,'frozen') and (sys.frozen=="windows_exe" or sys.frozen=="console_exe"):
    texturePath="visual\\"
else:
    texturePath = os.path.split( __file__ )[0] + "/"
del sys
```

For me worked change `texturePath=...`to another directory, for example C:

```
import sys
if hasattr(sys,'frozen') and (sys.frozen=="windows_exe" or sys.frozen=="console_exe"):
    texturePath=os.path.abspath("C:/")
else:
    texturePath = os.path.abspath("C:/")
del sys
```

Save it and MOVE the TGA archives from visual_common to C:/ (or to the chosen place) and finally try to build the .exe from the console

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

For this works...