# Pyinstaller with vpython FileNotFoundError glow.min.js

Tags: pyinstaller, vpython

When I compile my python program as a 'one file' with the VPython 7 library, I get the following error in the command line box at run time. Not sure what to add to my spec file or code to collect file when program is frozen.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI106402\vpython\vpython_libraries\glow.min.js'

I tried adding file to spec file but no luck.

a.datas += [ ('glow.min.js', 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython_libraries\glow.min.js', 'Data')]

Comment: I don't know anything about "one file" or a "spec file", but you might find some help from the VPython forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

Comment: This answer was very helpful to me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998318/python-converting-a-vpython-program-into-an-exe

Comment: In my spec file, my datas line looked like this for macOS:
```datas=[
        ('/Users/mcanulty/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vpython/vpython_data', './vpython/vpython_data'),
        ('/Users/mcanulty/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vpython/vpython_datac', './vpython/vpython_datac'),
        ('/Users/mcanulty/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vpython/vpython_libraries', './vpython/vpython_libraries'),
        ('/Users/mcanulty/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vpython/vpython_librariesc', './vpython/vpython_librariesc'),
]```

Comment: and for windows:
```datas=[
 ('C:\\Users\\mcanulty\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\vpython\\vpython_data', '.\\vpython\\vpython_data'),
 ('C:\\Users\\mcanulty\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\vpython\\vpython_datac', '.\\vpython\\vpython_datac'),
 ('C:\\Users\\mcanulty\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\vpython\\vpython_libraries', '.\\vpython\\vpython_libraries'),
 ('C:\\Users\\mcanulty\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\vpython\\vpython_librariesc', '.\\vpython\\vpython_librariesc'),
 
 ]```